# visual studio 2010 toolbox standard controls missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, toolbox

I have created an `asp.net` project in visual studio 2010 ultimate edition.

I can't see Standard, Data etc toolbox tabs, I can only see Telerik and HTML controls.

I tried to reset the toolbox, tried to delete `C:\Users\mypcuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\*.tbd`.

I also tried `devenv /ResetSkipPkgs` but nothing worked for me.

Please suggest a Solution thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This may help you.

In the Toolbox, select the tab where you want to add the control.

Right-click the Toolbox and select Choose Items from the shortcut menu.

The Choose Toolbox Items dialog box opens. The following illustration shows the Choose Toolbox Items dialog box.
[image]

Comment: The toolbox tabs will not show up unless you are in design view when working on the file that needs the control. Try that.

Comment: I am working on aspx page and they are not shown in designer view :(

Comment: Gotcha. Are you able to see them for other projects or solutions. Sometimes closing all open files within visual studio and restarting visual studio will fix it. You can also try - tools - Import and export settings and reset your current settings. Hope this helps or others can provide you with solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try to right click on the Toolbox and select "Reset Toolbox"

The common controls should appear in the Dialog Editor list along with all the MFC ones that I seem to be limited to when the problem happens.

I have this happen frequently. I don't know what causes it, but this fix always works and is fine for me since I didn't customize anything.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked for me in VS2012 with a MFC project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you...
In Visual studio, go to view-toolbar-check standard and layout..
Then restart the visual studio and be sure on design page and check for toolbox.. 
Now the standard toolbox items will appear.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the Future Viewer of this page

VS 2010 standard ToolBox cannot be viewed.

Mostly this is happen on a first run.

It solved the problem with `Ctrl + Alt + X` in your keyboard.