# visual studio 2013 toolbox missing standard

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to practice asp.net using visual studio 2013 web express, however I found the toolbox is missing the standard tool which I have to use label, button ,,,such tools, how can I solve this problem ?
I have [looking into this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753639/5678590) but it did not work for me,, thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you try minimising HTML controls(by clicking on the small icon near HTML), and checking other tools below that?

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking the Toolbox and select "Reset Toolbox" 
it will reset the toolbox back to default.

[image]

Comment: same, it did not work,,I use a very old computer AMD Athlon cpu, 9 years ago  hardware ,,does it matter? but OS upgrade to windows 10