# Visual Studio 2017 Many WPF objects missing from the toolbox

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and selected Desktop-Development for .net features.

Now when I'm starting up Visual Studio and create a new WPF project, theres no advanced objects in the toolbox like the arc Control or more Effects other than BlurEffect and DropShadowEffect. These and many others are just missing. When I look in the object browser in Visual Studio Blend, I can't find them there either.

Do I need to install something else explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I found it out: You have to manually select "Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET" in the Components section of the installer. This will actually install all the advanced WPF Controls, which where missing for me.

Those where always installed from VS Installer versions 2012, 2013 and 2015 automatically (its a package of 100mb).

I can just imagine that the Idea of a much more modular installer led the designers there to think "we need to make the installation faster so push out every little package that was used commonly throughout the last 5 years.".

And then they thought: "BUT hey, when it comes to the Xamarin installation, let's KEEP IN all the Google-Emulators for Android which pack a WHOPPING 17 GB!!!"

They surely thought also: "Most people wont need these, since they either have a android device on their own or they use one of our emulators, which are vtx enabled, so 10 times faster than googles emulators, and ours also only need 1 GB of disk-space. But well, we wanted to make a fast installer after all, so let it pack our customers drives full of stuff they don't need at all".

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on a category in the toolbox and click on the "Choose items" option and try to find the tools that you are missing:

[visual studio 2010 toolbox standard controls missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753589/visual-studio-2010-toolbox-standard-controls-missing)

Blend is more design friendly than Visual Studio though so you shouldn't be suprised if you see more options in Blend. After all, Visual Studio is a programming/coding tool and Blend is a design tool.

You rarely (or never) use the toolbox to add elements to a WPF view in a "real-world scenario. In fact it is quote common to disable the designer altogether: http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/03/24/disable-the-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio/. If you are a serious WPF developer you should really learn XAML and MVVM :)

Comment: Hello. By now I actually found out that you have to Choose the "Blend SDK" manually in the Installer Components-List.