# Opening VS 2015 project in VS 2017 | install Missing Features

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

While Opening VS 2015 project in VS 2017 getting this error of Install Missing Features

[image]

When I press on Install button the loader comes and then the error comes, after that nothing happens

[image: Loader comes]

[image: Error]

Visual Studio 2017 Version Details
[image: Visual Studio 2017 Version Details]

**Stuffs Tried till now**

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331910/visual-studio-2017-many-wpf-objects-missing-from-the-toolbox) : Installed Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127718/how-do-i-add-features-to-visual-studio-2017) : Not able to do any of the steps given in this link

[Link 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-network-related-errors-in-visual-studio) : Have done this setting to set proxy settings for VS2017

**Env Info**
Using Corporate account having proxy settings to access internet

Please help on how to proceed ahead.

Comment: `Link 2 : Not able to do any of the steps given in this link`? Hmm, you aren't able to launch the Visual Studio installer?

Comment: Installer opens up, and when I click on Modify, nothing happens. Getting the same InvalidOperationException Error.

Comment: Sounds like a bad install. Probably need to run the cleanup tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio

Comment: download latest installer from Microsoft page (15.6.6) which has better proxy support, repair/Update VS2017 and install the .Net Desktop workload.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by having the Nuget Package "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" installed for a project, without actually having all the package files present. (I don't know how this happens.)

Edit the project file of the unloaded project (right-click in Solution Explorer > edit). Remove this line near the top:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

Right-click the project again > Reload Project.

Visual Studio might prompt you to restore Nuget packages. Click yes.
If it doesn't prompt you, right-click the solution in Solution Explorer > Restore Nuget Packages.