# Why would most items in VB dialog toolbox become disabled

Tags: vb.net, toolbox, disabled-control

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on a VB Forms project. Everything was fine, I had produced 3 dialogs with various combinations of items.

Then I wanted to add some Static Text to let the users know what each Textbox represented.

To my surprise, when I opened the ToolBox I got this:

[image: ToolBox]

I don't remember doing anything strange, no idea what could have caused it.

I've tried to reset the toolbox, but to no avail. I open a new project, and the same thing, not possible to add dialog items.

Everything else works fine. I can edit, run and debug code. I can even copy items, like text boxes, and paste new ones...

Someone suggested that the other way to restore this edit option was to delete all the .tdb files of the project, but I don't seem to have any, would that have been for another version of VS?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I had something like this happen in the past and Reset Toolbox seemed to work for me.  [This has some other possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753589/visual-studio-2010-toolbox-standard-controls-missing)  If your solution is something different, don't hesitate to post your own answer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "VB Forms project"? Do you mean Windows Forms, because *Sequence Diagram* and *Dialog Editor* are not normal sections for WinForms.

Comment: Yeah, Windows Forms. I had already done a lot of development, so it was working, and for some reason, I now have no editor to add components.

Comment: every once in a while, as I am debugging, after a simple change, I try to recompile and it fails saying it can't find the object file or something. The only way out is to close the program and restart. Doesn't happen very often, and when it does everything continues as normal. It's possible (not sure) that this could have happened before this problem arose. Hard to tell, because I didn't notice a problem until I needed to add a new element to the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff has recently happened to me when I had installed a software plugin for my VB project. It's so easy to fix.

Just reset the Visual Studio's user preferences data from `Tools > Import & export settings > Reset data` and you're good to go.

Comment: It should be working, because I had only this problem. You can try a hard reset for Visual Studio by going `Tools > Import & export settings` and selecting *Reset* option.

Comment: Yesss... That worked. Thanks! I upvoted, but it doesn't register publicly  because I don't post here often.